# Put the sub-command output between apostrophes

Tags: bash

I want to pass a file to the mv command. However I'm trying to pass first file from the `ls` command. The file name looks like `my music.mp3` so I have to put the sub-command output between apostrophes in order to make it correctly recognized by the mv command. I'm trying to do something like that (below), but it doesn't work. I know it can be done using `echo`, but I believe there's a better way.

```
mv '`ls | head -1`' 'Music/my playlist/'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Back-ticks `` have been deprecated in favor of subcommands ran with `$(...)` instead.  Also, you should replace the single-quotes with double-quotes in case you have file names with spaces in them.

**Note:** You can use the single-quotes around the file names with spaces, but you should use the double-quotes around the subcommands.

```
mv "$(ls | head -1)" "Music/my playlist/"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Should be noted that it doesn't matter which type of quotes (single/double) because of the spaces, but because double quotes allow interpretation of the content, like variable expansion or command substitution, whereas single quotes don't.

Comment: @ByteCommander Good point.  It's been a habit of mine to use the doubles over the singles.  Now I just have to think of good wording to note into my answer.  =)

Comment: Good documentation on quoting: http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Quote.html

Comment: @Ravexina Thank you!  That is a good document.  I am going to bookmark that for future reference.  =)